# create new sheet and sum based on same value in multiple rows excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

If someone could help me out that would be fantastic and thank you in advance

I have big excel list with different orders that looks like this example

[image]

What I would need to do is to: 
 Search and match data based on column I and then when it matches it should merge together that rows, and create 1 row like 8th and 9th row here. 
  But it should do a sum of costs (column H) and for row G seats to create a format like 10-11 here, but if I have multiple rows where there are numbers 10,11,12 it should format 10-12. ANd all this new rows should go in the new sheet/tab in the same excel file.

Answer (score 0):

This should be fairly straight forward using Pivot tables. You can simply use "Order Number" in the column and simply aggregate everything else. If you haven't used pivot tables before the following link should get you started:

https://www.excel-easy.com/data-analysis/pivot-tables.html

There are a couple of options for the concatenation issue. The easiest option is to  use Power query for this. The following link highlights a couple of possible ways to do this:

https://superuser.com/questions/453041/grouping-labels-and-concatenating-their-text-values-like-a-pivot-table

I would recommend Power query as it is the easier option.

Comment: If you are using 2016 version you can also use Power query for this

Comment: I've tried with pivot tables but not sure how to merge column G to be in the format 10-11, or if I have multiple seats for example seats 10,11,12,13 format to be 10-13

Comment: Added an edit which explains how you can do it using Power query